# Replacing rusty trunk dampener - one or both?

Tags: skoda, trunk, fabia

I noticed that one of the trunk (boot) dampeners, on my Skoda Fabia mk2 estate from 2011, is rusted to the point of the metal bulging.
I decided to replace it, thinking that if it fails, the boot is going to be heavy to operate. but due to some glitch I only got one in the mail.

I assume that there is no issue with me replacing just the one, besides it potentially being stronger than the old one? Or should I wait and replace them as a pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with replacing just one. Normally I would replace both of them, because when one fails, the other is usually not far behind. There's no real safety concern with only replacing one and it shouldn't cause any damage or problems with the boot lid.